# How to correctly setup a DHCP server in the following network?

Tags: router, ip, ipv4, ipv6, dhcp

So, I've got the following Network Configuration:

[image: My network configuration on a hardware level]

Assume that, on the graph, **"PCs"** can be any device that needs an IP(apart from a router).

Now, as explained on my title, I want to run a DHCP server to deliver IPs to the network. However, I am not sure which server I have to set up as the DHCP one, since everything I've seen so far on DHCP setup assumes you only have 1 server setup.

Do I setup **Router A** as the authoritative one and the other 3 to relay all DHCP- related packages to **Router A**? Or do I do something else?

I'm new to this so I would really appreciate any help at all.

Comment: In this situation, you would _not_ use the crappy DHCP server that is built into the router OS. You would use a real DHCP server and set up DHCP relay on any router on a foreign network (DHCP scope)..

Comment: I see. And are you aware of how I can setup each router to relay DHCP packets? @RonMaupin

Comment: Yes. On a cisco device it is the `ip helper` interface command. It is actually very easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'correct' way. Basically, you can either setup or connect **a DHCP server to each subnet**, or set up **a central DHCP server** and configure relays on the routers (or switches). Both variants can also be mixed. Note that fully-fledged DHCP servers on a server machine are usually preferable as router-based DHCP is most often limited.

Usually, it's more practical to have a central DHCP server (usually on one of your server boxes, alternatively on a router or wherever) than multiple separate servers. As the central server represents a single point of failure, you should consider making it redundant.

I'm afraid, the specifics are off topic here (host configurations etc.).

Comment: So, essentially, I either make **all** routers DHCP servers or I make, say, router A my DHCP server and the other servers relay the DHCP-related packets to router A. If I follow the second case, do you have any pointers as to how I can configure routers B, C and D to relay those packets to router A?

Comment: You should abandon the DHCP-server-is-a-router thought. Unless you're talking about off-topic, consumer-grade devices that isn't too commonly the case. We could likely help your with configuring on-topic devices (business-grade routers or switches with optional, paid support) but you'd need to provide the exact models and their current configs in your question.